# Which text encoding to expect when capturing a program's output to stdout?

Tags: winapi

I'm capturing the output of an external program as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output). Now I am wondering about the text encoding to expect when reading the pipe's data into a memory buffer using `ReadFile()`.

External programs can write to `stdout` in various ways, for example:

- using `printf()`
- using `wprintf()`
- using `WriteConsoleA()`
- using `WriteConsoleW()`
- ...

So will I get UTF-16 text if a program uses `wprintf()` or `WriteConsoleW()` to write to `stdout` and 8-bit text (depending on the default console encoding) if a program uses `printf()` or `WriteConsoleA()`? Or what encoding will text captured from an external program be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TD;DR: It depends on the program.

`WriteConsoleA/W` cannot write to pipes, only to the console so they are not a factor here.

A program that uses `WriteFile` directly will write in whatever format the data given to the function is. Most likely the active ANSI codepage, the OEM codepage, or UTF16-LE.

A program that uses the wchar_t print functions and the Microsoft C run-time can choose the output format (`_O_WTEXT` (UTF-16? with BOM), `_O_U8TEXT`, or `_O_U16TEXT`) by calling [`_setmode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode) or `_wsopen`.

Most programs are not going to output UTF16-LE unless you give them a switch to enable this feature (`cmd.exe /U` etc.). The best approach if you know nothing about the programs but you prefer Unicode would be to look for a BOM and if it is not present, try to parse as UTF-8 and if/when that fails, fall back to the ANSI or OEM codepage. If you have a fair amount of buffering you could also try to detect UTF-16 without a BOM with `IsTextUnicode`.

If you are attached to a console you can try to influence the other process by calling `SetConsoleOutputCP` but I doubt anyone will listen.

See also:

- [Myth busting in the console](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2010/10/07/10072032.html)
- [Conventional wisdom is retarded, aka What the @#%&* is _O_U16TEXT?](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.html)